# transport_address not matching unicast host values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi Elastic Search users,

We are seeing a rather strange issue. I have reviewed the email archives and I do not see this issue addressed already. We have discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false in our elasticsearch.yml. The cluster comes up and the state is green, and the nodes are aware of each other.

The strangeness is that the transport_address value returned in the cluster state query does not match the values in discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts - it is using a different interface on the machines.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` are used only for initial discovery. In other words they are used by a node to find other nodes in the cluster. An interface that a particular node is binding to or publishing for other nodes to use doesn't depend on `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` but instead it is controlled by `network.host`, `network.bind_host` and `network.publish_host` settings. See the [network](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/network/) section of Elasticsearch guide for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Setting network.host fixed the issue. Looks like first non loopback address on the box was the management ip and that was being picked up by elasticsearch.